# how to refresh a view content pane each time a group of tabs is clicked without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-views

I have used `Swiper` in my views to create a slide of contents, and have a views content pane which brings 4 items at a time sorted randomly.

A random sort works with a page refresh but i want this view to get updated without page refresh when a user changes the slide in content section.

I have tried [JQuery Ajax Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load) module but it doesn't support views.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know what ajax is expecting exactly you can make the script on your own and provide that data. Start from empty php file, add drupal's bootstrap code at start:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

And after that drupal is fully functional. Use views, load nodes or what ever you need. Format output as it's needed, print it out...